# Cmake KDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND

Tags: cmake, macports

Using Cmake to build cutecom and have this error in the cmake GUI:

'KDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND'.

I have googled around it but not having much luck

I've got all the KDE stuff I could find with macports.

Comment: Variable `KDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE` expected to point to `kde-config` executable. Find this executable on you system, and pass option `-DKDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE=<path-to-kde-config>` to cmake.

Comment: Hi, 

I've run 'sudo / find -name kde-config' and I'm not finding it at all, but when I re-run 'sudo port install kdelibs4' I'm getting a message to say 'no broken files found'. Surely this means it's not on my system? But when I google for downloading this executable, I'm unable to find a suitable download?

Comment: It could be that `kde-config` is just synonim to `kde4-config`, as described in [that answer on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/426642). You may set variable `KDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE` pointed to `kde4-config` executable, or create symlink named `kde-config` and repeat configuration process, so variable will be set automatically.

Comment: Yea, I do have kde4-config...thanks!

It was here: '/opt/local/bin/kde4-config'

Comment: You may set variable KDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE pointed to kde4-config executable, or create symlink named kde-config and repeat configuration process, so variable will be set automatically.

Comment: Setting variable `KDECONFIG_EXECUTABLE` is described in the my first comment to the question. Creating symlink is described in the referenced answer on askubuntu.

Comment: Ah thanks so much. I used the one linked....(the simlink) I'm not getting errors now but cutecom is still not working....But at least I have a different problem now!